# How can I fix a "NoMethodError" exception?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in Videos#index

Showing /rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views/videos/index.html.erb where line #12 raised:

undefined method `upvoted_videos' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #12):

9: <div class="home_options">
10:     <ul class="home_options_list">
11:         <li> <%= link_to "Top Songs", videos_path, :class => "top_songs  chosen_home_option" %> </li>
12:         <li> <%= link_to "#{pluralize(current_user.upvoted_videos.count, 'Upvoted Song')}", upvoted_videos_path, :action => "upvoted_songs", :class => "upvoted_songs" %> </li>
```

This is in my user model:

```
def upvoted_videos
  self.voted_videos.where("value = 1")
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is throwing an error because you are trying to call `upvoted_videos` on a nil object. This means that `current_user` is nil. I would add some sort of check to see if `current_user` is not nil before calling calling `upvoted_videos`

Comment: it happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get a `NoMethodError` always just go to check why, and it says that you are trying to call something on a `nil` object. 
This means you must not have a `current_user` before doing this operation, so make sure someone is signed in.

Also it is good practice to have a fallback on functions like this, like a 
`<% unless current_user.nil? %> ...(Do function here)... <% end %>`
or something in the view